# find such $f$-holomorphic function that satisfy the following condition $(Re(f(z))^3-(Im(f(z))^3=8$

Tags: complex-analysis

Good time of day. I don't know how to solve this problem

Let $f$-holomorphic function that satisfy the following condition $(Re(f(z))^3-(Im(f(z))^3=8$ for all $Re(z)>1$ and for all $z$. Is it possible to find such f so that $f'(2)=3/2$?

Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

And from Cauchy Riemann equations we have

$\frac{u(x,y)}{\partial x} 3u^2(x,y)=\frac{v(x,y)}{\partial y} 3v^2(x,y)$

$\frac{u(x,y)}{\partial y} 3u^2(x,y)=-\frac{v(x,y)}{\partial x} 3v^2(x,y)$

And as a result $v=0$ and $f(z)=const$

And it isn't possible such functions that $f'(2)=3/2$

I hope is it right?

Comment: Use Cauchy Riemann equations to show that $f$ must be a constant.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thank you for your answer. If you don't mind please can you explain this in more detail? Thank you